# Code with intermediate computations - which style is more efficient?

Tags: python, performance

I have a function that performs a number of computations on an array variable. The code will be running on a cheap low performance single board computer (like the Raspberry Pi, I do not know the exact board at this time). This function is a major function of the overall program. I require the program to run fast even with heavy data present in the array variable. I am worried about the memory management and overall speed of the program. I am thinking of two ways for this.

***Question:*** Should I use different intermediate variables, or should I use the same variable for the different computations. Which of the two below methods would be efficient in terms of memory management and processing-speed? Is there a better way than the below?

Option 1:

```py
def function_1(a):
    #some code
    b = computation_1(a)
    #some code
    c = computation_2(b)
    #some code
    d = computation_3(c)
    #some code
    return d
```

Option 2:

```py
def function_2(a):
    #some code
    a = computation_1(a)
    #some code
    a = computation_2(a)
    #some code
    a = computation_3(a)
    #some code
    return a
```

Note: I know of this coding style:

```py
computation_2(computation_1(a))
...
```

However due to the different nature of the various functions, I need to do some preprocessing before sending to them, represented by the "#some code"

Comment: Benchmark both versions and find out?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I do not know or have the SBC with me now, and my program may later be used on different platforms. Hence my question

Comment: @TransistorOverlord Benchmark on a PC.  The memory usage and relative performance will be the same on a PC and SBC.

Comment: Do you *have* to use Python?  Usually the memory consumption and CPU efficiency of a compiled language like Rust or C++ will be better.  (But try it and see - get a RasPi and prototype on it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the CPU time difference will be negligible.

However, Option 1 creates b and c, and only when it returns will b and c be available for garbage collection. Option 2 doesn't keep intermediate results hanging around for so long. If the intermediates are small, this is also irrelevant. But if they are objects occupying tens or hundreds of megabytes (on a Pi with only 512Mb or 1Gb of RAM), this could make the difference between a program which swaps or crashes for lack of RAM, and a program which does not.

So use Option 2, provided the intermediates are of no use the moment the next step is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The difference would be negligible. The overhead of registering a new variable and assigning it to the result is too small to be noticed.